# natural language understanding algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, references, natural-language, language-models

I am doing some research into how smart personal assistants work like siri, alexa etc. I have found that it is using automatic speech recognition to turn the speech into weighted text form and then perform Natural language understanding on it to actually find the meaning of the text. I have been trying to get more information about natural language understanding and what techniques/models are used to get the right meaning and am having problems finding anything really specific. Does anyone know more specifically how NLU finds or ranks the context/meaning of text?